# can we use paypal to pay a list of people at once?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I have a web application which would need to pay a very large number of people, but only small amounts.  It would have access to their Paypal emails, and nothing else.  I want to use Paypal, because credit cards are more dangerous, but there is a transaction fee for every payment, and remember, I'm paying small amounts to many people.
Is Paypal suited for large numbers of small payments?  (If it helps, I could do all the payments at the end of each month)?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  I recommend the MassPay API.